# Quickbooks not fetching all items

Tags: quickbooks, quickbooks-online

I am adding invoice to quickbooks online using Keith Palmer's QuickBooks PHP DevKit.

I developed a demo model in localhost, and its working fine and adding invoices to my quickbooks online.

but now when i uploaded it on server, it's not fetching items by this code, and returns false,

```
$ItemService = new QuickBooks_IPP_Service_Term();
$items = $ItemService->query($Context, $realm, "SELECT * FROM Item WHERE name = 'test1' ");
```

in localhost its fetching data perfectly,

i only made change in $dsn, before uploading it to server,

```
$dsn = 'mysqli://root:root@localhost/example_app_ipp_v3';
```

can anyone please tell me where could be the issue, Keith Palmer Plz ?

Answer (score 0):

If the *only* thing you changed is the $dsn string before uploading it to your live server, then *you haven't uploaded any of the connection credentials/OAuth information to the live server*.

Go back through the "Connect to QuickBooks" OAuth flow by clicking the "Connect to QuickBooks" button in your application.

Then, try the script again.

**IF YOU HAVE TROUBLE** you need to post enough detail to let us actually diagnose your problem. Post the output of the included example "diagnostics.php" script:

- https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php/blob/master/docs/example_app_ipp_v3/diagnostics.php

Also, post the last request/response you sent to/from Intuit's servers, by doing this:

```
print($ItemService->lastRequest());
print($ItemService->lastResponse());
```

View > Source in your browser and post the output.